# Is it correct to say "she is 13 in this picture"?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct?

> She's 13 **in** this picture

Or

> She's 13 **on** this picture?

Or any other way of saying "she was 13 years old when the picture of her was taken"

Comment: **In**, not **on** (American English).  Apparently you are asking only about the preposition. But your sentences could be used both to make a guess or state a fact regarding the girl's age.

Answer (score 3):

Like others have said, a person, place, or thing in a picture or painting is always **in** it.

"The girl is 13 years old **in** the picture."

"There is a church **in** the picture."

If you are talking about something related to the physical picture itself (usually the surface) you would use **on**. For example:

"There is a scratch **on** the picture."

"There is some dirt **on** the picture."

"Somebody wrote **on** the picture."

*However* there are even some exceptions to this:

"The picture has a tear **in** it."

Answer (score 2):

**In** is used since her image is **part of the picture** (enclosed or surrounded by).

The picture itself is usually **on** the surface of ***something***:

> **canvas
>
>   photographic paper
>
>   a display device**